# Problems running Recursive Feature Elimination using Cross Validation in SkLearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-mining

I am currently working on a project in which one portion we would like to use a Filter method of evaluation in which we did correlation analysis but in the other portion, we thought it would be a good idea to do more or a Wrapper method feature elimination using cross validation. I found the recursive feature elimination package on Sci-kit learn.

I am loading my data into a Pandas data frame 'df':

```
df = pd.read_csv("/Users/rohinmahesh/Documents/Data_Mining_Project/bank-additional-full.csv")
df = df.reset_index()
```

After creating dummy variables I create the feature and label arrays:

```
x = df2.iloc[:, :-1]
y = df2.iloc[:, -1]
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3)
```

After running various models with accuracy as a metric (project specification), the most optimal model was Logistic Regression:

```
clf = LogisticRegression()
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

I am then evaluating the model with 3 fold Cross Validation (project specification):

```
pre_score = cross_val_score(clf, x, y, cv=3)
score = pre_score * 100
print(st.mean(score))
```

Now when I run the regular Recursive Feature Elimination, it is working:

```
rfe = RFE(clf, 3)
rfe = rfe.fit(x_test, y_test)
print(rfe.support_)
print(rfe.ranking_)
```

But when I try and run this using the RFECV, I am getting an error message:

```
rfe = RFECV(clf, cv=3)
rfe = rfe.fit(x_test, y_test)
print(rfe.support_)
print(rfe.ranking_)
```

I am new to this, so any help would be great!

Edit: I have gotten this to run properly (not sure what I did before that made it wrong) but I am getting this output, and I don't understand how everything is of rank 1. Could someone catch my mistake possibly?
[image]

Comment: And whats the error? Please post the complete stack trace of error

Comment: @VivekKumar Not sure what happened this time around, but it did end up running but it is running improperly, and it is ranking everything of the rank 1. I have attached the output with the edit that I have made to the post.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to post...
It simply means that the algorithm did find any performance improvements from dropping features.

All selected features have a rank of 1.
Only dropped features have a rank greater than 1.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33490026)